# How to write apache redirect for directory with slash, no slash or index.html

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I use mod-rewrite very often and am looking for a shortcut.

If I want to redirect both of these links

```
mydomain.com/tralalala/login
mydomain.com/tralalala/login/
```

I can do it with this statement:

```
 RewriteRule ^tralalala/login/?$ /redirect-page.html [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way that I can redirect all three of these URLS with a single statement :

```
mydomain.com/tralalala/login
mydomain.com/tralalala/login/
mydomain.com/tralalala/login/index.html
```

I don't necessarily want to redirect everything with a wildcard after "tralalala/login".

For example, this page I don't want redirected.

```
mydomain.com/tralalala/login/dont-redirect-this.html
```

I know I can do it with 2 rewrite statements, but I'd prefer a single statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^tralalala/login(/index.html|/)?$ /redirect-page.html [R=301,L]
```